# Java open source DMS framework

Tags: java, open-source, document-management, dms

Can anyone recommend good java open source DMS framework?
Thanks,

aviad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considered Alfresco, OpenKM and Knowledgetree.
I choose [Knowledgetree](http://www.knowledgetree.org/Main_Page) because it has DMS centric approach. IMO it is the most suited DMS solution for handling document repository needs along with a well defined method.